# How to remove '\t', '\n' or extra spaces from a string in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, trim, regexp-replace

I have a table in Postgres with following column:

```
col1
     The study was terminated early by the sponsor on 13 January 2014 due to a decision to modify     the drug development plan.   
     Due to positive preliminary results from other palifermin studies.   
     Asset terminated by PIB   
     Inconsistent training status of sniffer dogs   
     This study was terminated early due to poor recruitment   
     The study was terminated due to lack of recruitment.   
     The scientific director decided to terminate: low priority study with slow accrual   
     See Termination Reason in Detailed Description.   
     Investigator moved to new institution   
     This study was terminated for administrative reasons   
     The app was not completed in time to conduct a clinical trial on it within the funding grant's     award period
```

There are  leading and lagging spaces in the string and either '\n' or '\t' in between. I tried following queries but seems nothing is working out.

```
select btrim(col1, '\s') from table;

update table
SET col1 = upper(substring(REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '(\s+)', '') from 1 for 1)) || lower(substring(REGEXP_REPLACE(why_stopped, '(\s+)', '') from 2));

update table
set col1= regexp_replace(col1, E'[\\n\\r\\f\\u000B\\u0085\\u2028\\u2029]+', ' ', 'g' );

select distinct replace( replace( replace( col1, E'\n', '\n' ), E'\t', '\t' ), E'\r', '\r' )
from table;
```

Any suggestion would be really helpful here.

Answer (score 4):

To use backslash escapes in string literals, you have to prepend them with an `E`; see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#id-1.5.3.5.9.5.2).

So try

```
btrim(col1, E' \t\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use trim() function [SQL String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html)

```
TRIM([LEADING | TRAILING | BOTH] [characters] FROM string)
```

you can find example here:

[postgresql-trim-function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-trim-function/)
[trim function](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/trim-function.php)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the  issue by:

regexp_replace(why_stopped, '\s{2,}', ' ', 'g')